# css make the image height according to the height of div container

Tags: css, css-float

HTML Code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <img src="http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA17555.jpg" width="222px">
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p>
    <p>Main content</p
 </div>
```

Visit `http://jsfiddle.net/dlamichhane/Hv2mq/1/` to about the know the detail code scenario.

[image]

I have a main div container which wraps two divs. In the first div it only contain the image tag and in the second div the size of the content grow dynamically (sometimes there are fewer contents and sometimes there are more contents). In such situation, how can I make the height of the image to fit with the height of main div container. Note: the image shouldn't be streched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple straight forward answer.
There are a few different ways to accomplish this, an extensive article about this is [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) on css-tricks.